# Putting Google+ and Facebook reviews on my website with Schema.org

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, schema.org, user-reviews

I have a some reviews on my Facebook page and Google Plus page. Can I put those reviews on other 3rd party review page using schema?

Will it be counted as duplicate content by Google? Is it right for SEO?

Answer (score 4):

According to **[Common structured data errors](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/prototype#common-sd-errors)** of Google Search Guides:

> ***Here are some common causes of structured data manual actions***. A review is written by the **site** or person providing the product or service, rather than a customer or independent, unpaid reviewer.

Also similar information is in the **[Review snippet guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review#review-snippet)** of Google Search Guides:

> Google may display information from aggregate ratings markup in the Google Knowledge Cards. The following guidelines apply to review snippets in knowledge cards for local businesses: *Ratings must be sourced directly from users. * Sites must collect ratings information directly from **users** and not from other **sites**.

Do not do this, as this is contrary to Guides of Google.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Issue With This. Google Will not Count it as Duplicate Content. 
But It will be the Best to Integrate with FB, Google Reviews directly on the site.

You can use FB, Google Tools Or Any WP Plugin if for Wp site. But ALso SAfe other methods.

Answer (score 0):

That's not duplicate content and you will not have any problem with Google as long as you follow the [general guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies) (especially, make sure the ratings are visible to visitors)

> The content referred to by the structured data is not hidden from the user.

There is no evidence that structured data (schema) has a direct affect on organic search rankings, nonetheless, it will help you get the attention of the users and improve search results CTR.

Comment: How would it not create duplicate content to take reviews from other sites and put them on your own?

Comment: It's only a small part of the site, far from being duplicate content https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If the webpage has the exact same content as indexed Google+ pages then this is likely duplicate content.

If on the other hand the webpage has Google+ content that isn't exactly the same as indexed Google+ pages then this is likely original content.

If you add your own content to the page and also show Google+ content than this is very likely original content.

Answer (score 0):

No. schema.org is not a programming or markup language and gives you no method for inserting content into a web site.

Comment: I think they are asking if they can copy the reviews to their website and mark them up with structured data to get Google to use the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be safe to use schema markup if you treat the reviews as *citations*.

Duplicate content won’t be a problem if you give enough credit to the source. Also the website where the reviews will be displayed is also referred  in your FB and G+ pages.

Use http://schema.org/Review have a look a the  *citation* and *sameAs* properties.

I found this example at [moz](https://moz.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-creating-onsite-reviews-testimonials-pages)

```
"review": {
    "@type": "Review",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Reviewer's Name",
        "sameAs": "<a href="http://link-to-persons-profile-page.com">http://link-to-persons-profile-page.com</a>"
    }
    "datePublished": "2016-09-23",
    "reviewBody": "Reviewer's comments here...",
    "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating"
        "worstRating": "1",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "ratingValue": "5"
    }
},
```

In this example they use the *sameAs* property, I believe that’s what you should do.

How many is too many? It depends, but I will just use just a few citations, you don’t need that much, do you?