# Can I add third party reviews to our site for the purpose of aggregate review ratings without triggering duplicate content penalties?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, rich-snippets, user-reviews

Is there a good way to display reviews that people have left on sites like Yelp, City Search, Google, etc on your own website without triggering duplicate content issues?

It's hard to get reviews, so I'd like to make the most out of the ones that I get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting Google+ and Facebook reviews on my website with Schema.org](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113293/putting-google-and-facebook-reviews-on-my-website-with-schema-org)